# Strange WithEvents thing

Tags: vb.net, winforms

Very simple case.
A Form Class inside a Button that triggers a MsgBox

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        MessageBox.Show("TEST")
    End Sub
End Class
```

then I create a new class Class1 and move the Sub Button1_Click to that class

```
Public Class Form1

End Class
Public Class Class1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Form1.Button1.Click
        MessageBox.Show("TEST")
    End Sub
End Class
```

And I get a Failure

> Failure BC30506 Handles clause requires a WithEvents variable that is defined in the containing type or one of its base types.

then I modified like this:

```
Public Class Class1
    Public WithEvents Form1.Button As EventThrower()
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Form1.Button1.Click
        MessageBox.Show("TEST")
    End Sub
End Class
```

And now I get 2 Failures

> Error BC30412 ' WithEvents ' variables must have an as clause.
>
> Error BC31412 'Handles' in classes must specify a WithEvents variable,
>   'MyBase', 'MyClass' or 'Me' qualified with a single identifier.

Can Somebody explain me this in a simple way ?

**UPDATE 1:**
The Solution coming from Visual Vincent removes the Error but by clicking the Button1 on Form1 the MessageBox gets not fired, so practically its not working.

```
Public Class Class1
    Public WithEvents Button1 As Button = Form1.Button1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        MessageBox.Show("TEST")
    End Sub
End Class
```

How can I get the Button1 on Form1 fired from within the Class1 ?

Comment: What's an `EventThrower`??

Comment: A EventThrower is a Object that throws events.

Comment: You are not going to be able to click a button in one class and have an event raised in another class (which may not even be instantiated).

Comment: can class not inherit properties?

Comment: I've never heard of an `EventThrower` before. Is it a custom class/library?

Comment: I have edited my answer. It works for me now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
Public Class Form1

'Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
'    MessageBox.Show("TEST")
'End Sub

   Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
      AddHandler Button1.Click, AddressOf Class1.ButtonClick
  End Sub

End Class

Public Class Class1

   Public Shared Sub ButtonClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
      MessageBox.Show("Clicked from ButtonClick")
   End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: I agree, manually attaching the handler is way more practical, readable and understable here.

Answer (score 2):

*but by clicking the Button1 on Form1 the MessageBox gets not fired, so practically its not working.*

```
Public WithEvents Button1 As Button = Form1.Button1
```

Based on your code `Form1` is a class. Where `Form1.Button1` mean that class `Form1` have static variable `Button1`.

Obviously you have `Button1` in your `Form1` class, which can be accessed only through instance of `Form1`. For getting right instance of `Form1` you need pass that instance as parameter to `Class1`.

Then your code:

```vb
    Public WithEvents Form1.Button As EventThrower()
```

1. Name of variables cannot contain dot (as mentioned by @Visual Vincent)
2. You can declare only individual variables—not arrays—with WithEvents.
   `... As EventThrower()` is declaring array of type `EventThrower`

So you need change the line to be type of `EventThrower`

```
Public WithEvents MyEventThrower As EventThrower
```

Main problem of your code that you try use instance of button and handle it's `Click` event in another class, which not a good practice.

If you want move code of `Click` handler to the another class, do it with reverting dependency. Your Form will have dependency on class which contains logic

```
Public Class LogicClass
    Public Function ExecuteSomeLogicAndReturnValue() As String
        Return "TEST"
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class MyForm Inherits Form
    Private _Logic As New LogicClass()

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.MyButton.Click
        Dim value As String = _Logic.ExecuteSomeLogicAndReturnValue()
        MessageBox.Show(value)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Your code seams interesting, but I can't see how it is answering my question. Please be more verbose.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what an `EventThrower` is, but your variable declaration is invalid. After the access modifier (in this case `Public`) a name is expected, and names cannot contain dots.

I would suggest you do something like this instead:

```
Public Class Class1
    Public WithEvents Button1 As Button = Form1.Button1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        MessageBox.Show("TEST")
    End Sub
End Class
```

To make this work without a class instance you can mark everything as `Shared`. **EDIT:** As I suspected you have to access the class at least once or else the handler won't get attached. Calling an empty method should suffice:

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Class1.Initialize()
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class Class1
    Public Shared WithEvents Button1 As Button = Form1.Button1
    Private Shared Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        MessageBox.Show("TEST")
    End Sub

    Public Shared Sub Initialize()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: You suggestion is removing the errors but clicking on Button1 on Form1 doesn't fire the MessageBox

Comment: @eichertc : You need to create an instance of the class or make it all `Shared`. Let me update the answer.

Comment: @eichertc : Possibly, you will also need to access something within the class so that the handler gets attached. I'll look into that more when I get back...

Comment: OP want handle Click event of button from Form1 with method from Class1. Variable `Button1` in `Class1` have nothing to do with `Form1` even you make it `Shared`.

Comment: @Fabio : What do you mean? If he's using the default form instance to show/access his form then this will work. If you examine my code you'll see that I assign `Form1.Button1` to the variable, so the `Button1` variable has nothing to do with `Form1` _**other than**_ holding a reference to `Form1.Button1`.

Comment: Default form instance, for example `Form1.Show()` will create new instance of `Form1`, which cannot reference already created instance of `Form1`

Comment: Of course you can. If you use the default instance and the form is shown it will always refer to the same instance. Call `Form1.Show()` twice and it will only show up one.